# convert exception access special chars

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

when I put data from excel to access database and access automaticaly set number type on fields but in excel I have number fields with '-' char. When I put data in access fields with '-' are empty. It's conversion error but access don't report it. How I can catch this error?

```
            myErr = Err.Number
        myErr2 = Err.Description
        If myErr > 0 Then
                              PrintMyLogNew myErr & " " & myErr2
        End If
```

Comment: How do you put data in Access? In query designer you can set "Fail on Error" and in VBA use `dbFailOnError` option of the `.Execute` method. Both will throw a datatype mismatch error (if that's the case).

Comment: `dbFailOnError` will rolls back updates but I don't want this. When I try catch `Err.Number` in `myErr` and in if statement it shows that `myErr=0` but it is wrong because it dont import all data, skip number with `-` .